# Reading multiple character arrays in C using scanf

Tags: c

```
  char a[100],b[100],c[100];
  scanf("%[^\n]",a);
  printf("%s",a);
  scanf("%[^\n]",b);
  printf("%s",b);
```

The compiler seems to be reading the first read but skips the second read. Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't use `scanf`. Use `fgets` and strip of the `\n` if you don't want it

Comment: Or, if you want to use `scanf`, you can consume and discard the newline with `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", a);`. (Added `99` to avoid buffer overflow).

Comment: Tip: When I/O is not working as expected, the 1st line of defense coding is to **check the result** value of the functions.  `int cnt = scanf("%[^\n]",b); if (cnt != 1) printf("Unexpected scan %d\n", cnt);` would have helped this code a lot to narrow the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because of un handled <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Use `fgets()`

Try this :-

```
char a[100], b[100], c[100];
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", a);
fgets(b, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", b);
```

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: The `newline`  generated in scanning `a` is assigned to `b`

Comment: Testing the return value of `fgets()` would prevent potential undefined behavior on early end of file.

Comment: @anoopknr [The newline generated in scanning a is assigned to b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710295/reading-multiple-character-arrays-in-c-using-scanf#comment90381945_51710329)  --> No.  with `scanf("%[^\n]",b);`, `b` would not get a `'\n'` assigned.